# Rearrange Date filter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

I have a stored procedure in which I'm selecting couple of columns on the basis of date column provided. The result should be based on current financial year
which starts with the 5th of January.

But how can I create logic for self updating date filter which will set to
the start of financial year automatically without updating stored procedure every year?

```
SELECT
    SUM([RetailPrice]) AS Retail,
    SUM([CostPrice]) AS Cost,
    SUM([MarketPrice]) AS Market
FROM 
    PriceDetail
WHERE
    [UserID] = '0029'
    AND [Date] >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-01-05')
```

Comment: Is `[UserID]=0029` going to work as you expect here? `0029` would be implicitly parsed as `29`, and `UserID` would be implicit cast to an `int`, which means if you have values like `'0029'`, `'29'` and `'029'` would all be seen to have the same value.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake

Answer (score 3):

If you never run in the first five days of the year:

```
select SUM([RetailPrice]) AS Retail,
       SUM([CostPrice]) AS Cost,
       SUM([MarketPrice]) AS Market
from PriceDetail
where [UserID] = 0029 and
      [Date] >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), 01, 05);
```

If you need for it to work the first six days of the year:

```
where [UserID] = 0029 and
      [Date] >= datefromparts(year(dateadd(day, -5, getdate())), 01, 05);
```

Comment: `DATEFROMPARTS` was a new feature in SQL Server **2012** - so if the OP is on this or a newer version, this code will work nicely; if he's on an older version, it won't work

Comment: Considering that the financial year starts on 05 Jan, I wonder if the OP actually wants `>=`; otherwise they are always missing the first day of the year out. This is certainly what the OP's logic is, but thought worth noting.

Comment: @marc_s hopefully the OP isn't using a version of SQL Server that is completely (or about to be) out of support then. :)

Comment: @Larnu: yes - hopefully - but you'd be surprised (or shocked?) how many folks are still on 2008/2008R2, or even 2005 or even 2000 (!!!!) ....

Comment: I'm neither surprised or shocked, @marc_s, but I would say I'm concerned.

Comment: @Larnu: well, not to worry, as long as you're not responsible for that server :-)

Comment: @marc_s . . . I think SQL Server 2008 becomes deprecated this month (or sometime very soon).  SQL Server 2012 is already pretty old.